# Simplest way to pass multivalue arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Trying to make this work
I have a script which needs to get a multi value argument separated by space

```
e.g ./script.sh  -f something1 something2
while [[ $1 -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
    -u | --username )   shift
                              USER=$1 ;;
    -p | --password )  shift
                              PASSWORD=$1 ;;
    -o | --out )       shift
                              OUT=$1  ;;
    -f | --file )  shift
                              PACKAGE=$1 ;;
    -g | --group )     shift
                              GROUP=$1  ;;
    -n | --name )      shift
                              NAME=$1  ;;
    -help | --help )      help
                                       ;;
    download )         ACTION="download"
                ;;
    delete )           ACTION="delete"
                ;;
    * )                usage   exit 1
    esac
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is like the following:

```sh
while [[ -n "$1" ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        -u | --username) USER="$2" ;;
        -p | --password) PASSWORD="$2" ;;
        -o | --out) OUT="$2" ;;
        -f  | --file) PACKAGE="$2" ;;
        -g | --group) GROUP="$2" ;;
        -n | --name) NAME="$2"  ;;
        -t  | --test) TEST1="$2"; TEST2="$3"; shift 2 ;;
        -help | --help) help; exit 0 ;;
        download) ACTION="download" ;;
        delete) ACTION="delete" ;;
        * ) usage; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

To pass multiple arguments separated by a space/spaces as a single parameter, make sure to quote them either with single/double quotes.

```sh
./script.sh  -f 'something1 something2'
```

or

```sh
./script.sh  -f "something1 something2"
```

Comment: `~  bash -x standalonetest.sh -u damn -p password
+ [[ -n -u ]]
+ case "$1" in
+ USER=-u
+ shift
+ [[ -n damn ]]
+ case "$1" in
+ echo usage
usage
+ exit 1` Problem is that it always goes to usage and exits.

Comment: Copied your script and passing the arguments. It always ends in "usage" and exists

Comment: What I'm using is literally what I've wrote. Tested same scenario with the example you've given me, but it ends at " * ) usage; exit 1 ;;" and it exists

Comment: See my latest edited.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a shell builtin for such cases - `getopts` (not `getopt`)
https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/getopts.1.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":n:u:" opt
do
  case $opt in
    n) name="$OPTARG" ;;
    u) user="$OPTARG" ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2
    exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

echo "Name: $name"
echo "User: $user"
```

Comment: This works when adding quotes, indeed. I quess there is escaping double quotes. How can u add in the cases positional parameter. Like ./script sh something -n name. Can getopts do that? I couldn't properly see